# How to make backtick commands fail in Makefiles?

Tags: makefile

The following Makefile target doesn't fail:

```
test:
    echo `blah`
```

How can I can make it fail besides running the backticked command on its own on the previous line.

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.0
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: You could replace `echo ...` with `false`. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want to template a string with a value coming from a command, and if the command fails and the value isn't filled in I want the target to fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a make problem, not really.  Make simply waits for the shell it invoked to finish, then checks the exit code.  If it's `0` (success) then make assumes the job succeeded.  If it's any other value, make believes the job failed.

If you run this command at the shell, you'll see that the exit code is not preserved:

```
$ echo `bah`
  ...errors...
$ echo $?
0
```

There's nothing make can do about this.  You'll have to find a way to ensure that your command exits with a failure.  You haven't given us enough information about what actual command you want to run to help you solve this problem.

*ETA*

There are lots of possibilities.  But since you've still not provided any real specifics, I'll just suggest one possibility: you can test the resulting value to see if it was empty or not:

```
test:
        var=`blah`; [ -n "$$var" ] || exit 1; ...do stuff with $$var...
```

Comment: See the comments in the question - the specific command is `terraform output <output>`